# How to show Todays date on load in bootstrap daterange picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, date

Please find my program below,

How to show Today's date in the div.. as per below example .. by default it show Todays date but its showing previous month to today's date... if I click on Today from drop down still it shows date from previous month to today's date. On page load itself how to show  **from** and to date as Today's date

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />        

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        //alert($('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY')));
    }
    cb(moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment());

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

});
</script>        

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="reportrange" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 20%">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
            <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes...But i need start date and end date in two different javascript variable on form submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added following code in your code, In this we are calling `'getDate()'` on click of button,  try this code

```
<input type="button" id="GetCalenderDate" value="Get Selected date" onclick="return getDate(); " />

<script>
    function getDate() {
        alert($('#reportrange span')[0].innerHTML); //Using Jquery selector
        alert(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML); // using Javascript getElementsByTagName()
    }
</script>
```

Edit: Use split function if u want to store start date and end date in different variables

```
var selectedDate = $('#reportrange span')[0].innerHTML.split('-');
alert(selectedDate[0]); //Start date
alert(selectedDate[1]); //End date
```

Comment: How to get Today's date.. as per above example which I've gave.. by default it show **Todays** date but its showing previous month to today's date... if I click on Today from drop down still it shows date from previous month to today's date. On page load itself how to set from and to date as Today's date